# Files walk doesnt return absolute paths only filename

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, nio, jfilechooser

I have a folder in my Desktop with a structure similar to this:

```
-/documents
   -/00
     -1.html
     -2.html
   -/01
     -3.html
     -4.html
   -/02
     -5.html
     -6.html
```

I want to get all files inside `/documents` so I made this:

```
ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
    fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    fc.showOpenDialog(fc);
    File[] file = fc.getSelectedFiles();
    for (File f : file) {
        try {
            Files.walk(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath())).filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    .forEach(p -> paths.add(p.getFileName().toString()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return paths;
```

However I'm getting only the filenames, like this:

```
1.html
2.html
```

Etc. I can't figure a way to get every file path like this:

```
/documents/00/1.html
/documents/00/2.html
/documents/01/3.html
/documents/01/4.html
```

Etc. 
Using `p.getFileName().toAbsolutePath()` didn't make the trick, I got paths like if they were inside my workspace:

```
C:\Users\n\workspace\test\1.html
```

Comment: What is the actual absolute path of the folder 'documents'?

Comment: @BlackPearl `C:\Users\santi\Desktop\documents`

Comment: I tried out your code and I get the absolute path correctly. You wouldn't get `C:\Users\n\workspace\test\1.html` unless you choose a file in that path. And do you want only `/documents/00/2.html` and not `C:\Users\santi\Desktop\/documents/00/2.html` ?

Comment: @BlackPearl yeah I would want the full path `C:\Users\santi\Desktop\documents\00\1.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `p.getFileName().toString()` try using `p.toString()`. you should get the actual path output of all the files.

I created a similar structure and If i run the above program as below:

```
ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    fc.showOpenDialog(fc);
    File[] file = fc.getSelectedFiles();
    for (File f : file) {
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            Files.walk(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath())).filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    .forEach(p -> paths.add(p.toString()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(paths);
```

I get the below output:

**[D:\document\00\1.html, D:\document\00\2.html, D:\document\01\3.html]**

Is this the output you are expected ?